# Eigenvalues of the sum of a diagonal and a unit matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to find information on the eigenvalues of an $n \times n$  matrix A such that

$A = D + J$

Where $D$ is some complex valued diagonal matrix, and $J$ is an matrix consisting of all $1$'s.
When $D$  has identical values, the problem is equivalent to finding the eigenvalues of $J$.

So my question is this:
*If $D$ has non-identical values (specifically, non-identical imaginary components), 
is there an elementary way to compute the eigenvalues of $A$ ?*

The problem comes from linearising about the origin of a system of $n$ near identical coupled resonators. $D$ relates to the behaviour of each resonator, $J$ relates to the coupling process.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a formula. Recall that $\det(I-AB)=\det(I-BA)$ for any matrices
$A$ and $B$ such that both products $AB$ and $BA$ are defined. Now
$$
 \det(tI-D-J) = \det(tI-D) \det(I-(tI-D)^{-1}J).
$$
If $u$ is the column vector with each entry equal to 1 then $J=uu^T$ and
$$
 \det(I-(tI-D)^{-1}J) = \det(I-(tI-D)^{-1}uu^T) = \det(1- u^T(tI-D)^{-1}u) = 1-u^T(tI-D)^{-1}u.
$$
If we write $\phi(M,t)$ for the characteristic polynomial off $M$, this yields
$$
 \phi(D+J,t) = \phi(D,t) \left(1-\sum_i \frac1{t-D_{i,i}}\right).
$$
The sum is equal to $\phi'(D,t)/\phi(D,t)$ and therefore the right side equals $\phi(D,t)-\phi'(D,t)$.

Comment: Thanks very much, this was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Well, $J$ is a rank-one matrix. So this calculation is nothin but a special case of the Sherman--Morrison formula.

Comment: @Denis: Could you say another word or two about making the connection to the Sherman--Morrison formula?  I see that $J$ here is a particular rank-one matrix, but I don't see what this has to do with calculating an inverse $(D+J)^{-1}$ where $D^{-1}$ is already known.  I can generalize the above answer for arbitrary rank-one $J$, but then the sum has no obvious interpretation.

@Chris, is there intuition for the RHS, $\phi(D,t)-\phi'(D,t)$?  What's the usefulness of a derivative of a characteristic function?

Comment: @Jess: I have no intuition for $\phi(D,t)-\phi'(D,t)$. The ratio $\phi'(M,t)/\phi(M,t)$ turns up in combinatorics in various places.
I am not sure I really understand what "usefulness" means here.


Comment: Could you explain this further, with J being arbitrary rank one matrix. And how to compute the eigen values in that case?

Comment: To avoid confusing future readers: note that this answer does not provide a way to compute the eigenvalues, as asked, but only an expression for the characteristic polynomial.