# Eigenvalues of sum of an adjacent matrix and a constant

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvector, matrices

$A$ is an [adjacent matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) of a network. $la$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A$ and $Va$ is its corresponding eigenvector.

I am interested in the following martix: $bA+c-dI$ ($b$, $c$, and $d$ are all real constants, $bA+c$ is obtained by multiply each element of $A$ by $b$ and then increased it by $c$, $I$ is the Identity matrix)

Let $lac$ be the largest eigenvalue of $bA+c-dI$.

I want to obtain an approximate function: $lac=F(la,c,..)$. Could you help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I clicked "close" by mistake---please count my "undo" of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy upper bound is $la+nc$, where $n$ is the dimension. This is because the matrix norm of a sum is no more than the sum of the matrix norms.

An easy lower bound is $k+nc$, where $k$ is the average vertex degree. This is because, for all $v$, $v \cdot Mv/||v||^2$ is no more than the highest eigenvalue of $M$. The vector of all $1$s provides this lower bound.

If your graph is approximately regular, $la$ is not much more than $k$, and these bounds will be relatively close.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer!

Could you provide more details about how to get the lower bound $k+nc$ from " for all v, v⋅Mv/||v||2 is no more than the highest eigenvalue of M. "

If I change the interested matrix from $A+c$ to $bA+c$ ($b$ and $c$ are both constant).

Should the largest eigenvalue of $aA+c$ in the range of $[b*la+nc, b*k+nc]$?

Thanks.

Comment: The vector of all $1$s turns into a vector of, for each vertex, the degree of that vertex plus $c$. The dot product of that with itself is twice the number of edges plus $nc$. Its norm is $n$ so we can divide and get that estimate.

Due to constant scaling of matrices scaling their eigenvalues, your second statement is correct.

Comment: When $v$ is the vector of all $1$s, $v \cdot Mv/||v||^2=(nk+n^2c)/(\sqrt{n})^2=k+nc$, right?

That is really helpful for me.

Could give me the reference for "for all $v$, $v \cdot Mv/||v||^2$ is no more than the highest eigenvalue of $M$." What is the theory foundation for this?

Thanks.



Comment: Since the eigenvectors are perpendicular, you can diagonalize the matrix by changing orthonormal basis. So proving it for diagonal matrices is sufficient. Then explicitly write down the formula for $Mv \cdot v$ and compare to $||v||^2$.

Comment: I was trying to prove ``for all vector $v$, $v \cdot Mv/||v||^2$ is no more than the highest eigenvalue of $M$.'' But I was blocked after getting the equation that $Mv \cdot v=\lambda_1(lv_1 \cdot v)^2+\lambda_2(lv_2 \cdot v)^2+ ... \lambda_n(lv_n \cdot v)^2$. Could you help on the proving process blow?

Let $\lambda_i$ represents a eigenvalue of matrix M and $lv_i$ represents its corresponding eigenvector.

Comment: If $M$ is diagonalizable, it can be represented as $M=PDP^{-1}$ where, 1) $D$ is a diagonal matrix with its diagonal entries: $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, .. \lambda_n$, 2) $P$ is an orthonormal matrix with its column vectors: $(lv_1, lv_2, ... lv_n)$.

Since $P$ is orthonormal, $P^{-1}=P^{T} \Rightarrow M=PDP^{-1}=PDP^{T}$

Comment: \begin{eqnarray}
Mv \cdot v=PDP^{T}v \cdot v=(lv_1, lv_2, ... lv_n)D(lv_1, lv_2, ... lv_n)^{T}v \cdot v \\
=(lv_1, lv_2, ... lv_n)(\lambda_1 lv_1, \lambda_2 lv_2, ... \lambda_n lv_n)^{T}v \cdot v \\
=(lv_1, lv_2, ... lv_n)(\lambda_1 lv_1 \cdot v, \lambda_2 lv_2 \cdot v, ... \lambda_n lv_n \cdot v)^{T} \cdot v \\
=[(\lambda_1 lv_1 \cdot v)lv_1+(\lambda_2 lv_2 \cdot v)lv_2+ ... (\lambda_n lv_n \cdot v)lv_n] \cdot v \\
=(\lambda_1 lv_1 \cdot v)lv_1 \cdot v+(\lambda_2 lv_2 \cdot v)lv_2 \cdot v+ ... (\lambda_n lv_n \cdot v)lv_n \cdot v
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: \begin{eqnarray}
=\lambda_1(lv_1 \cdot v)^2+\lambda_2(lv_2 \cdot v)^2+ ... \lambda_n(lv_n \cdot v)^2
\end{eqnarray}

Thanks.

Comment: Let $\lambda_1$ be the highest eigenvalue, then $\lambda_i \leq \lambda_1$ so the expression simplifies to $Mv \cdot v \leq \lamda_1 \sum (lv_i \cdot v)^2$. Since $lv_i$ is an orthonormal basis, $\sum (lv_i \cdot v)^2=||v||^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\lambda(A)$ denote the eigenvalues of any matrix $A$. First note that $\lambda(bA-dI) = b\lambda(A)-d$. So, we can ignore the scaling and shifting. Now, let us look at the slightly more general result (at least for the case $c \ge 0$ in your question).

If $\alpha_1\ge \cdots \ge \alpha_n$ are the eigenvalues of a matrix $A$, and $\beta_1 \ge \cdots \ge \beta_n$ are the eigenvalues of the matrix $A+xx^T$. Then, we have the following interlacing result:

\begin{equation*}
  \beta_1 \ge \alpha_1 \ge \beta_2 \ge \alpha_2 \ge \cdots \ge \beta_n \ge \alpha_n.
\end{equation*}

I mention in passing, for a more general rank-1 perturbation, along with perhaps other useful specializations, you might benefit from skimming the paper ["Eigenvalues of rank one perturbations of unstructured matrices"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.0618) by A.C.M. Ran, M. Wojtylak, and also by chasing some of the references they provide for the simpler case that you are treating (namely, the rank-1 perturbation is: $c11^T$)---see also [this paper.](http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~mehl/papers/mmrr2.pdf)

Comment: Also, for numerical purposes, you might want to look at: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/67924/eigenvalues-of-the-sum-of-a-diagonal-and-a-unit-matrix